# Issue with missing style ref in heading

Tags: microsoft-word

Sorry if it's confusing with a right to left language and all. Basically my header consists of 3 parts, style ref for Heading 1, underneath it style ref for heading 2 and the page number. This table is full of pictures (the text is copied pics from a pdf). The heading 1 shows up in the header in the first page (the left page) and is mysteriously missing in the second page (the one on the right).

Don't know if it's connected, but normally I just copy the pics from the pdf and paste it. This time they had black lines underneath and I had to change their layout to square to get rid of them. Those pics with the issue did not allow me to choose their style on the home ribbon.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry picture removed, apparently you need more rep...

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.